# AutoMapper Projection - date/time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I have a DateTime field in my Entity, which needs to map to 2 separate fields in the ViewModel for date and time i.e.

```
// Entity
  public partial class Event
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    }

// ViewModel
public class EventAddEditViewModel
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String StartDate { get; set; }
        public String EndDate { get; set; }
        public String StartTime { get; set; }
        public String EndTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Looking at [this example](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection), I have the following mapping:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Event, EventAddEditViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.Date))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StartTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.TimeOfDay))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDateTime.Date))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.EndTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDateTime.TimeOfDay));
```

which is great. However, how do I reverse the mapping i.e. Mapper.CreateMap() so that it also maps when the form is POSTed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar to you, however I have StartDateTime as a DateTime Property on my ViewModel, and have two int properties for Hours and Minutes 
e.g.

```
// ViewModel
public class EventAddEditViewModel
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int StartHour { get; set; }
    public int EndHour { get; set; }
    public int StartMinute { get; set; }
    public int EndMinute { get; set; }
}
```

This means that I can do the mapping thus

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Event, EventAddEditViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.Date))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StartHour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.Hour))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StartMinute, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.Minute))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.Date))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndHour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDateTime.Hour))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndMinute, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDateTime.Minute));

Mapper.CreateMap<EventAddEditViewModel, Event>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(src.StartDate.Year, src.StartDate.Month, src.StartDate.Day, src.StartHour, src.StartMinute, 0)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new DateTime(src.EndDate.Year, src.EndDate.Month, src.EndDate.Day, src.EndHour, src.EndMinute, 0)));
```

You should consider changing your viewmodel properties along those lines as integers will be easier to work with, however if they have to be strings, you'll need a way to parse out a DateTime object from your strings.  Depending upon the format of your strings, something along these lines should work

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EventAddEditViewModel, Event>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.Parse( src.StartDate + " " + src.StartTime)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.Parse(src.EndDate + " " + src.EndTime)));
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to keep hour:min together in the ViewModel so that its easier for users to enter/pick a time (similar to Google Calendar).

Answer (score 1):

@StanK, I have simplier mapping syntax for this case:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EventAddEditViewModel, Event>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StartDate.Add(src.StartTime.TimeOfDay)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EndDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDate.Add(src.EndTime.TimeOfDay)));
```